# Returned Dictionary From Parse Function Not Getting Stored in the Output

Tags: scrapy

In my Scrapy spider class, I have several functions to parse different types of URLs. It comes to a point where if a regex search is not found it will call the parse_product() function directly with the current response as a parameter and return the data from that function else it must send a form request with the parse_product() as the callback.

The issue is that the data is not coming in the output in the first case.

In the Scrapy documentation, it says I need to return a dictionary in the callback function for it to execute in the output pipeline but only the items returned from the form request made in the else statement are there in the output.

```py
   def parse_variation(self, response):
        self.logger.info("Parsing Variation")
        url_search = re.findall(variation_request_url_pattern, str(response.body))
        if not url_search:
            self.logger.info("URL SEARCH IS EMPTY")
            data = self.parse_product(response)
            #No Output with this statement
            return data
        else: 
            for url in url_search:
               yield FormRequest(url=url, body=body callback=self.parse_product)


    def parse_product(self, response):
        self.logger.info("Parsing Product")
        data = {}
        data["url"] = response.url
        data["name"] = response.xpath(title_xpath).extract_first()
        return data
```

Only the output from the Request in the else statement comes. Why is it that?

Comment: What is the URL to which you want to scrape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `yield` anywhere in a Python function, the return value of that function becomes a `generator` that can be used to iterate over the values that it yields.

Although `return data` in your `parse_variation` callback is valid Python, it does not do what you think it does. This is a common mistake in Scrapy, so much in fact that there [is a proposal to log a warning when it happens](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3869).

Switch it to:

```py
yield data
```